# CSS animation - paper open/close fold

Tags: css, jquery-plugins, jquery-animate, css-animations

I have problem with animation flow to open/close this paper. Heres what I've got
https://jsfiddle.net/upw1buds/3/

I have three main problems:

1. image is expanding beyond divs before paper fully open (However it should be visible during opening not showing after it). Thats doesnt look nice. Image is positioned in the right place.
2. Animation works strangely on Microsoft Edge
3. During closing animation right side is expanding too far while its shrinking and I cant synchronize it with closing leaf.

I think problem is somewhere here

```
  $('.content').click(function(){
    $('.info-wrap').removeClass('info-wrap-open');
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('.tile').removeClass('info-bottom-front-opening');
    }, 310);
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('.info_bottom').removeClass('info_bottom_wider');
      $('.tile').removeClass('tile_opening');
    }, 450);
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('.content').removeClass('content_show');  
    }, 500);      
  });
```